# Escape a preset column name in PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have mySql statement below.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `myTbl`.uploads('id','name','group') VALUES (:id,:user,:group)";
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
```

GROUP is a reserved command in mySql. How can I escape this so that I can execute my prepare statement?

Thanks.

Comment: Backticks are for escaping identifiers, not single quotes. You already used them for the table name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Identifiers** such as columnNames and tableNames shouldn't be wrap with single quotes, but instead with backtick. Wrapping with single quotes converts the identifier to become string literals.

```
INSERT INTO myTbl.uploads(id, name, `group`) VALUES (:id,:user,:group)
```

- [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/mysql-when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)